Is it possible to use the PHP exec() command for a 'fire and forget' CuRL request?
I have the following test code:
        $url = "https://MyAPIdomain/MyAPIendpoint.php";
        $contenttype = "Content-Type:application/json";
        $postfields = array("ordernumber" => 6392842);
        $postfields = json_encode(json_encode($postfields));

        $command = 'curl --header "'.$contenttype.'" --request POST --data '.$postfields.' '.$url;

        exec($command." > E:/websites/wmfltdonline/subdomains/smartwaste/www/logs/error.txt");

The exec() works fine, except that it is waiting for a response from the call before continuing. Having read around on this I was expecting the exec() to fork the process and continue.
Is it possible to use exec() as a 'fire and forget process' for a CuRL POST? In this case I am calling an external API with a parameter that will invoke a process that is self-contained, takes a long time and required no user response.

The exec() function in PHP waits for the command to complete before continuing, which is why you're seeing it wait for the response. To run a command asynchronously (i.e., as a "fire and forget" process), you need to detach the process from the parent. In Unix-like systems, you can achieve this by redirecting the output to /dev/null and running the command in the background. For Windows, you need a different approach.
$url = "https://MyAPIdomain/MyAPIendpoint.php";
$contenttype = "Content-Type: application/json";
$postfields = array("ordernumber" => 6392842);
$postfields = json_encode($postfields);

// Asynchronous curl command for Windows
$command = 'start /b curl --header "' . $contenttype . '" --request POST --data ' . escapeshellarg($postfields) . ' ' . $url . ' > NUL';
exec($command);


I had seen the /dev/null examples and perhaps that is what misled me as far as the difference between UNIX and Windows.
The answer above is still not behaving asynchronously. I have hard coded the string being submitted to the command (to avoid mistakes) to start /b curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "{\"ordernumber\" :6392842}" https://MyAPIdomain/MtAPIendpoint.php > NUL
I put a usleep() in the endpoint to force it to take a while so I can guarantee it is 'waiting' for the response.
